# On tapping a button, it doesn't work

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am a beginner about Sencha Touch and on the way learning it.

Following codes which I wrote by using Sencha Touch 2.1 don't work.
I can see a button on a browser, however on tapping the button, this doesn't alert.
Please tell me what what is wrong.
Sorry for my poor English, for I am Japanese.
Directory structure:

```
(root)---app.js
       |-app---view--Main_view.ja
             |-controller--Main_cont.js
```

[app.js]

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    views: ['Main_view'],
    controllers: ['Main_cont'],
    launch: function() {
        Ext.Viewport.add(Ext.create('MyApp.view.Main_view'));
    }
});
```

[Main_view.js]

```
Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
    fullscreen: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        pack: 'center'
    },
    items: [
    {
    xtype : 'button',
    text : 'Button',
    id : 'action'
    }
    ]
});
```

[Main_cont.js]

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.Main_cont',{
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        control: {          
            '#action':{
                tap : function() {
                    alert('tap');
                }
            }
         }
    }
});
```

Comment: any error message in the console?

Answer (score 2):

With buttons, you can set a "handler" attribute rather than a tap listener:

```
xtype : 'button',
text : 'Button',
id : 'action',
handler : function(){
    alert('tap');
}
```

Comment: generally this works but I do not recommmend using this. It breaks MVC conventional architecture

Comment: @ThiemNguyen Using 'handler' doesn't break anything.  This is exactly how you should use the button.  Within the handler function you can fire an event that the controller is listening for.  That's exactly how mvc works.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the handler allows you to control scope.  If you use 'this' inside the handler it will normally be the button itself, however if you want to access the wrapping object that contains the button element - to call a method of the container, for instance - than you can set 'scope: this' before declaring the handler attribute.  I use this often.

Comment: imho you always have a way better choice: use controller with refs/controls. It provides us a reference to the button object itself, so it's not difficult to traverse up its parent. Definitely it's way more convenient just to use `handler` but I personally like logic parts to be in controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'button[id=action]' : {
    tap : 'handleTap'
}
```

where `handleTap` should be a function defined in controller.

if you have defined its view in `refs` you can even do this:

```
'mainview button[id=action]' : {
    tap : 'handleTap'
}
```

this has worked for me